# status of services in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I am trying to get the status of a Windows service from code running in an ASP.NET website. Here is my code:

```
ServiceController dev1 = new ServiceController();
dev1.MachineName="mac_name";
dev1.ServiceName = "Adobe Acrobat Update Service";

string Dev_Status1 = dev1.Status.ToString();

`
```

In last line i am getting an error

> cannot open 'adobe acrobat update service' on computer 'mac_name'" InvalidOperationException

Comment: So, what's your question? And how could we possibly help you answer it based on the information you provided?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i need status of a service running in my local computer. so when i run this code i get the above error. i guess this may be permission related...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Adobe Acrobat Update Service" is the Display Name. The Service Name is AdobeARMservice. You can see this by opening the Services console services.msc and then right clicking on the service and clicking Properties. The Service Name and Display Name will both be displayed.

Make sure your web site has permissions to that computer.

Your code should be something like...

```
ServiceController sc=new ServiceController("AdobeARMservice", "computername");
```

If you want to get the status of a lot of services...

```
List<string> MyServicesToCheck=new List<string>() {"AdobeARMservice","2ndservicename","3rdservicename"};
foreach(string ServiceName in MyServicesToCheck)
   {
   ServiceController sc=new ServiceController(ServiceName);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status of "+sc.DisplayName+" is "+sc.Status);
   }
```

Comment: @user1139830:Another doubt.. Can u pls clarify that.. here i have mentioned only one service. I need status of 10 different services. So, for that, should i create 10 different ServiceController instances to get it all or is there any other easier way to get those?

Comment: @user3104758 I have edited my answer to include the status of multiple services.